# Is it possible to differentiate between two of the same shape in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, shapes

I'm trying to manipulate two different rectangles with CSS in two different ways.

Let's say I have:

```
.header {
    background-color: #000000;

.rectangle {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;

<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <h1>Head</h1>
</div>

    <div class="rectangle"></div>

</body>
```

Can I alter the top rectangle without altering the bottom one? E.g is it possible to change the size of the top rectangle and not the bottom one?

Comment: Use `.header .rectangle` to target only the first rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this. Target the rectangle class that is inside of the header by using `.header .rectangle`. I hope this helps!

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.header .rectangle {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <h1>Head</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="rectangle"></div>

</body>
```